# Swift If else statement not working as intended

Tags: swift, integer, comparison, option-type

I've tried to make an if else statement for a game similar to the high/low game. when you click the button, it seems like the statement is skipping over the `if NewNumber <= oldNumber` part and just going straight to the else part.  It should check the new integer against the old one and see if its higher or lower.
Only been doing swift for a little while so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
//Lower Button
@IBAction func lowerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newNumber = randomIntBetween(2, high: 26)
    var oldNumber: Int?

    func lowerNumber() -> Int {
        if newNumber <= oldNumber {
            correctWrongLabel.text = "You Were Correct!"
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(countWin++)"
        } else {
            correctWrongLabel.text = "You Were Wrong!"
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(countLose)"
        }
        return newNumber
    }

    let newValue = lowerNumber()
    randomIntLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
}
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking what the values of `newNumber` and `oldNumber` are?

Comment: Stick a break point in the method, and then print out the values of newNumber and oldNumber. If its going to the else statement, it means the newNumber is greater than the old number

Comment: The code you show isn't setting the value of oldNumber anywhere, so either you're missing some code, or that's your problem right there.

Comment: This looks like the code from the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769978/1187415 to your previous question. If that does not work then you should ask the author of the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing and `Int` value with a `nil` value of type `Int?`

```
var newNumber = 10
var oldNumber: Int?

if newNumber <= oldNumber {
    print("<=")
} else {
    print("Not <=")
}
```

Result

```
Not <=
```

In Swift an `Int` is not `<=` than `nil`, that's why the else branch is executed.

### Suggestions

`lowerNumber` is a pretty strange method:

1. it takes no params
2. it returns the minimum
3. and it also perform some actions

I suggest you to change it into something like this

```
func updateUI(old: Int, new: Int) {
    if new <= old {
        correctWrongLabel.text = "You Were Correct!"
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(countWin++)"
    } else {
        correctWrongLabel.text = "You Were Wrong!"
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(countLose)"
    }
}
```

Then when in your code you need to get the minimum between your 2 values just use `min`

```
if let oldNumer = oldNumber {
    let minimum = min(newNumber, oldNumber)
}
```

Comment: By the way, the `<` and `>` operators for optionals will be removed in Swift 3. This question is the reason why :)

Comment: @Sulthan: I didn't know and I agree, it's a good thing :) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: [Swift Evolution 0121](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)